# Convert email in Mail to iCal event

Tags: mac, email

I the email program Mail from Mac OS X Leopard, is it possible somehow to convert an email from the inbox into an event on the iCal calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - it's built into Mail: hover over the date and use the menu that appears.  See this [tip from Apple](http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/ical_event.html)